# Specify starting time of track within URL for SoundCloud?

Tags: soundcloud

Anyone know if there's a way to generate URL's for SoundCloud tracks that specify a start time for the song?  I'm looking for a way to force playback of streams at a certain time in the stream without having to do any processing on my end via the API.

Comment: Be attention this solution doesn't help while you work with streaming URL.
E.g. https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/299331197/stream?client_id={your_id}#t=47s

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As @bsz correctly noticed, we have released a way of specifying start time on the sound when linking to it, append `#t=12s` to the sound's URL to start it at 12th second, etc.

If the audio is long enough, you can use (e.g.) `#t=2h10m12s`.

Comment: Sucks that that's the case but at least I know now.  Thanks!

Comment: Also see: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47570/link-to-specific-point-in-time-on-soundcloud

Comment: Is there also an option for putting times into comments?

Comment: *If the audio is long enough, you _have to_ use hms (`#t=107s` will not work, but `#t=1m47s` will).

Answer (score 16):

They seem to have added a #t option but not sure if you can also give an stop time:

https://soundcloud.com/razhavaniazha-com/06-06-2013-razhavaniazha-afn#t=54:00

Comment: I tried getting this to work in an embedded widget, but it seems to only work when you link to the soundcloud. Anyone had any luck using it in a widget?

Answer (score 3):

You can also specify a start time one minute or over by appending

```
#XmXs
```

If you want a time right on the minute mark (e.g. 3:00), include 0 seconds (0s) in the time code (i.e. 3m0s), or else the start time will be ignored. It does not appear to support a start time over an hour.

Answer (score 2):

Click share and set or pick time
[image]

Comment: Where do you get that "at ....." time input option? It doesn't seem to be there (at least not anymore?) in Soundcloud's share feature.