# SoundCloud API: Using oEmbed to specify start and stop time for playing a track

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, soundcloud, oembed

I have a web application integrating with the SoundCloud API for searching and playing tracks. I can successfully stream tracks through the API using [SoundCloud oEmbed](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#oembed) like so:

```
scope.playTrack = function(track) {
  SC.oEmbed(track.permalink_url, { auto_play: true })
    .then(function(oEmbed) {
      scope.soundCloudWidget = $sce.trustAsHtml(oEmbed.html);
      scope.$apply();
    });
};
```

With the widget bound to the view:

```
<div ng-bind-html="soundCloudWidget"></div >
```

This is working as expected. My issue is I would like to stream a track in this way but with a **specified start and stop time**. I did some research and found a seemingly related [StackOverflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763072/specify-starting-time-of-track-within-url-for-soundcloud) that mentions one can:

*append `#t=12s` to the sound's URL to start it at 12th second*

This works when constructing a URL like:

https://soundcloud.com/griz/summer-97-ft-muzzy-bearr#t=54s

However, for `start = '54s'` I would like to do something like this

```
scope.playTrackSection = function(track, start) {
  SC.oEmbed(track.permalink_url, { auto_play: true, t: start })
    .then(function(oEmbed) {
      scope.soundCloudWidget = $sce.trustAsHtml(oEmbed.html);
      scope.$apply();
    });
};
```

or

```
scope.playTrackSection = function(track, start) {
  var url = track.permalink_url + "#t=" + start;
  SC.oEmbed(track.permalink_url, { auto_play: true })
    .then(function(oEmbed) {
      scope.soundCloudWidget = $sce.trustAsHtml(oEmbed.html);
      scope.$apply();
    });
};
```

But to no avail. **Is there any possible way to specify a start time in this type of context?**

Bonus points: Additionally is there any possible way to specify a duration or time when a streaming song should stop playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. [SoundCloud Widget API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget) to the rescue!

> In order to access the JavaScript object which provides the SoundCloud Widget API, add [this script](https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js) to your html page.
>
> This script exposes the `SC.Widget(/*iframeElement|iframeElementID*/)` function to the global scope. It allows you to control the widget from the parent page (the page the widget is inserted into). SC.Widget accepts the reference to the iframe element or its id.

So after adding this script I was able to do something like this:

```
scope.playTrackSection = function(track, startTime, endTime) {
  SC.oEmbed(track.permalink_url, { auto_play: true })
    .then(function(oEmbed) {
      scope.soundCloudWidget = $sce.trustAsHtml(oEmbed.html);
      scope.$apply();

      scope.iframe = document.getElementById('soundcloud_widget').querySelector('iframe');
      scope.widget = SC.Widget(scope.iframe);

      scope.widget.seekTo(startTime);
      scope.widget.bind('playProgress', function(needle) {
        if (needle.currentPosition >= endTime) {
          scope.widget.pause();
        }
      });
    });
};
```

With html:

```
<div id="soundcloud_widget" ng-bind-html="soundCloudWidget"></div>
```

It is also useful to know that `scope.widget.bind('xxxx', ....)` can be used to bind into several [Event types](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#events) of the Widget API. So if you want certain things to happen when a user pauses, plays, finishes, seeks, etc. you can hook into these events.

Comment: Can I see the code how you did it? I didn't get how you do it. If you can share the full code how you did it. It will so much help for me.